# How can I debug white screen when running install script?

Tags: installation

I'm doing a fresh install of drupal7 on Ubuntu following [these instructions](https://drupal.org/documentation/install).

When I get to the point of [running the install script](https://drupal.org/documentation/install/run-script) (by pointing the browser at localhost/drupal7/install.php) it just gives a blank screen.

Most questions/help about the Drupal blank screen relate to site setup but as this is a new install, I haven't created any sites yet so am unable to figure out what to do.

Does anyone know how to debug or move past this issue?

Comment: just check the file error_log in the Drupal root directory. See if you find any errors there.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your settings.php file and add

```
ini_set("display_error" , 1);
```

Comment: While it's not an answer of great quality, it could be helpful in debugging, which the question is about.

Comment: Thanks Bala for the information i am a new bee. It solved my problem so i thought it to shared it with others.

Comment: Dear Letharion 

How can i improve the quality. Please share some knowladge. Thanks in advance.